# Open Graph Debugger error "Failed to get composer template data", I can't share my website articles on facebook

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, developer-tools

**I'm having problems to share any article from my website Facebook simply nothing happens , I looked at the Open Graph Object Debugger and got the message :**

Debug Page > Composer Data Unavailable > Failed to get composer template data.

the website link is http://www.storyspotted.com/

I use Wordpress on the website.

I was wondering if we may know the reason why our contents are blocked and what can we do to unblock them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is due to the fact that you have two `og:description` meta tags.

sources: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/918385908182634/ / https://wordpress.org/support/topic/failed-to-get-composer-template-data-in-facebook-open-graph

Comment: So what should i do, some of my page are blocked for facebook share are some of are  not shown sharing thumbnail of post

Comment: I think some Wordpress plugins you use are in conflict, both of them add that meta tag. You should try disable your plugins and enable them one by one to see which of the add Facebook metatags, then try to have only one `og:description` in your HTML. If it works, maybe you should configure one of your plugin to not add that meta tag...

Comment: OK is there any setting in yoast because i am using it